# Is having pure sugar during a workout a bad idea?

Tags: gym, carbohydrate, sugar

On my gym days, I have developed a habit of mixing about 70 grams of [this complex, slow releasing carbohydrate supplement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MD8AAM) with about 60 grams of literally [pure sugar](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-Pure-Sugar-25-Lb/10403009), and about 24 ounces of water.

I find that this mixture keeps me energized throughout the entire workout, and I assume it's because of the sugar's high glycemic index, but is this a bad idea for some reason I don't know about? Is it bad for my health to be taking this much sugar this way?

If it matters, I'm 25 years old, 5' 10" tall, weight 140 Lbs, consume about 2,500 Calories a day, and just started the bulking phase after a long cutting phase.

Comment: Holy sh\*t, 60 grams? I feel the need to remind you that the recommended intake is 25 grams, *per day*. I might write a longer answer tomorrow if no one else has, but for now, you should really read this: http://www.webmd.com/diet/features/how-sugar-affects-your-body

Comment: @Alec Well, the rest of my daily diet is very low in sugar; mostly lettuce, chicken, carrots, protein supplements, and peanuts to snack on at night. Assuming those other meals get my daily sugar intake to about 80 grams, and assuming my maintenance level is at 1800 calories, that puts sugar at 45% of my discretionary calories; bellow the recommended 50% by the AHO, and at 13% of total calories, slightly above the recommended 10%.

Answer (score 3):

The health aspect of the question would get a better response in the [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) site.

Is it a good idea for a workout?  Pretty much every single "energy supplement" uses pure sugar as its base. They also typically include caffeine, b-vitamins, and other things, but the main active ingredient is the sugar. So it is widely used. Powerlifters will eat pure-sugar candy like gummy bears when they need explosive power for their heaviest lifts. Endurance athletes will use gels, or pure-sugar candy to sustain energy through their longest workouts.

However, I would suggest not becoming reliant a supplement to get you through a workout. It sort of defeats the purpose of training (in my eyes. Other opinions may differ). You also shouldn't really **need** a supplement to get you through **every** workout. Becoming reliant is usually a sign of another problem like:

1. You need more cardiovascular conditioning.
2. You need more sleep.
3. You need to re-adjust  your diet
4. You are doing too much. You need to scale back and build up.

Though for those occasional workouts where you just need the energy. You're about to attempt a new PR, you had a long day at work, the neighbor's dog kept waking you up all night, etc.  Then pop a few jellybeans and get through it.